# Change values displayed in Crystal Reports Group Tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Is there a way to configure or change the values displayed in the Group Tree displayed on the left in the crystal report viewer?

I ask because in the report I am grouping id numbers, but I display the names associated with the id. I want to display this name in the group tree as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Right click group header or footer in gutter
- Select 'Ghange Group...'
- Click 'Options' tab
- Enable 'Customize Group Name Field'; choose an existing field or build a conditional formula

Comment: I tried this and now the report viewer does not display the report. It just displays the toolbar and it ignores my size settings.

Comment: Don't know the issue but I tried it with a different report and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

- First of all create the Group
- Select the Field on which you want the group
- Click 'Options' tab check the Keep Group together and Repeat Group Header on each Page
- Select 'change Group...'
- Click 'Options' tab
- Enable 'Customize Group Name Field'; choose an existing field or
  build a conditional formula